# Reading specific lines from a file in a loop (optimization)

Tags: python

I'm reading specific lines from a text file. Here is my code:

```
file.seek(0)
for j, ln in enumerate(file):
   if j == line_number
      line = ln   # i'm getting the line
      break
```

It tooks a **long time** when I use this code in a "loop" where the line_number is random every turn.
I also tried linecache.getline() but it needs to be call linecache.clearcache() every turn, so its not better.

Is there a faster solution for that? Memory doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory truly doesn't matter:

```
lines = file.readlines()

line = lines[line_number]
```

You read the file in once, store it in memory, and access it from there.

Edit: Where memory matters:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

line = next(dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]==line_number, enumerate(file)))[1]
```

We can use `itertools.dropwhile()` to ignore the lines until we get to the one we need.

Answer (score 1):

**use this above the loop:**

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
 lines=[ln for ln in f]
```

**now access any line number inside the loop:**

```
lines[line_number]
```

Comment: Why have you used `rstrip()`? The asker didn't mention a need to do that.

Comment: @Hern for-in loop is much more memory efficient then readlines() , file will be accessed only once.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary What? Why is this more efficient than `readlines()`?

Comment: readlines() reads in an entire file at once, so In case of a huge file this method becomes memory inefficient. But for small files readlines() is much faster than readline().

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Except in your case, you may be reading line by line, but you are then constructing a list from it. If `readlines()` uses too much memory by making a list of all the lines, then you manually making a list will do so as well. Your statement only applies if you are working on each line, then throwing away that line.

Comment: @Lattyware http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, that only confirms what I said. Using `readlines()` is less efficient in general because you are reading all the lines in before doing anything with them. However, in this case, that is the aim, so you might as well use `readlines()` rather than a list comp.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getLine(fileObj, lineNo):
    [fileObj.readline() for i in xrange(lineNo - 1)]
    return fileObj.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing

```
import linecache
linecache.getline('myfile', line_number)
```